# use a django filter to indent a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I am having trouble indenting text from my template. I indent the start of the text using multiple `&nbsp` in my mainTemplate.html, but, if the text continues onto a new line, that new line is not indented. So, I have been trying to use a filter to correctly indent each line. My template uses an `{% include %}` tag to render and include the subtemplate (display_citations.html) of the text that I am trying to indent. Is it possible to store the rendered subtemplate as a string so that I can pass it to my 'indent' filter? If not, is there another way to indent the content of that subtemplate?

mainTemplate.html

```
{% for publication in value %}
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{% include "software/display_citations.html" with publication=publication url="/select_citations/"%}
{% endfor %}
```

display_citations.html

```
{{ publication.authors }}. {{ publication.title }}{% if not publication.title_ends_with_punct %}.{% endif %}{% if publication.journal %} {{ publication.journal }}.{% endif %}{% if publication.month %} {{ publication.month_long }}{% endif %} {{ publication.year }}.{% if publication.volume %}{% if publication.number %} {{ publication.volume }}({{ publication.number }}){% else %} {{publication.volume}}{% endif %}{% endif %}{% if publication.pages %}: {{ publication.pages }}.{% else %}.{% endif %}
<br><a href="{{url}}{{ publication.pk }}/?ris" target="_blank" download="Citations.ris">RIS</a>
```

views.py

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='indent')
@stringfilter
def indent(value, arg=1):
    import re
    regex = re.compile("^", re.M)
    return re.sub(regex, "\t"*int(arg), value)
```

I think what I need to do in mainTemplate.html is somehow create a string out of my subtemplate and then pass it to my filter...? Something like this perhaps:

```
text_to_be_indented = {% include "software/display_citations.html" with publication=publication url="/select_citations/"%}
{{ text_to_be_indented | indent:"4" }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you must use so many `&nbsp;`? Why don't you try `div` with a style `margin-left:20px;`?